# Using AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient to encrypt inside Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, .net-6.0, amazon-kms

I have a lambda function which uses below code for encryption inside .net6 lambda

```
[HttpPost("encrypt")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Encrypt([FromBody]string value)
{
    try
    {
        var region = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(_configuration.GetValue<string>("AWS_REGION"));
        var client = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient(region);

        var kmsKeyId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KMS_KEY_ID");

        var encryptResponse = await client.EncryptAsync(new EncryptRequest
        {
            KeyId = kmsKeyId,
            Plaintext = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value))
        });

        string encryptedValue = string.Empty;
        if (encryptResponse != null)
        {
            encryptedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptResponse.CiphertextBlob.ToArray());
        }

        return Ok(encryptedValue);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.LogError(exception, "An exception occured while encrypting");
        return BadRequest(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

The issue which I am facing is my lambda gets timeout and no exception from .net code. After debugging further I realized that execution is not progressing after `EncryptAsync` call(kind of getting stuck). The infesting thing is this code works whenI run locally from Visual studio 2022. My lambda has IAM policy to access the kms key like below as well.

```
statement {
    sid = "KmsAccess"
    effect    = "Allow"

    actions = [
      "kms:Encrypt",
      "kms:Decrypt",
      "kms:ReEncrypt*",
      "kms:DescribeKey",
      "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
    ]
```

Any idea why my code is getting stuck when I run in Aws?

Comment: Did you research anything? This is a very common issue when configuring Lambda functions in your own VPC. See [How do I troubleshoot timeout issues with a Lambda function that's in an Amazon VPC?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-vpc-troubleshoot-timeout)

Comment: I found that vpc endpoint for kms was not provisioned. After provisioning the same, it started working. Thanks